# require_auth( user ) not working in HelloWorld

Tags: permissions

I ran through the hello world [tutorial](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/your-first-contract).

First time I ran through using v1.6 of `nodeos` and it worked as advertised.

Upgraded to v1.7 of `nodeos` and the `require_auth(user)` did not restrict user from saying hi to other users as it did the first time I ran through it.

More confusing to me,  both Alice and Bob have the same public keys

```
root@eosnode5:/opt/eos/contracts/hello# cleos get account alice
created: 2019-03-27T01:49:46.500
permissions: 
     owner     1:    1 EOS7WX9jdhYLR5FPKFpfZMz6fFzzVewL4iEMtWHWDbUtY3JCbY4az
        active     1:    1 EOS7WX9jdhYLR5FPKFpfZMz6fFzzVewL4iEMtWHWDbUtY3JCbY4az

permissions: 
     owner     1:    1 EOS7WX9jdhYLR5FPKFpfZMz6fFzzVewL4iEMtWHWDbUtY3JCbY4az
        active     1:    1 EOS7WX9jdhYLR5FPKFpfZMz6fFzzVewL4iEMtWHWDbUtY3JCbY4az


cleos push action hello hi '["bob"]' -p alice@owner
executed transaction:   {"user":"bob"}
Hello, bob

cleos push action hello hi '["alice"]' -p bob@owner
executed transaction: 
hello <= hello::hi                    {"user":"alice"}
Hello, alice
```

Clearly not the desired effect.

here's the code,

```
class [[eosio::contract]] hello : public contract {
  public:
      using contract::contract;

      [[eosio::action]]
      void hi( name user ) {
           require_auth( user );
           print( "Hello, ", user);
      }
};
```

Any idea why the accounts `require_auth()` isn't working?  Is it because the have the same public keys?

Also,  anyone point me to an in depth explanation of the account structure.   That would be helpful.

Thanks!!!

Comment: It is not because of same key pairs, we can have as many accounts as we can using same keys, And they behave differently. For that you can explore scatter desktop and import the keys which you used for creating multiple accounts. `https://get-scatter.com/` you can use this link. Now coming to your problem of require_auth(user) it will work for every account. Try to use require_auth(_self) and don't pass any argument, So this case the account who push the contract will work and for any other account it won't.

Comment: I change require_auth( _self ) and I can still push alice as -p bob@active.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm Alice & Bob are using different keys to access their account, can do this with

```
cleos get account alice
cleos get account bob
```

Once confirmed, check what keys you have available to `cleos` when it attempts these commands, can list keys with `cleos wallet list keys` I believe.

If Alice & Bob's keys are in there, cleos might be mixing and matching, remove bobs keys and then run your test again.